# Simple JavaScript Misunderstanding

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS, and am having trouble with a simple script. To me it seems like when i push the button, it should change between black and red. But it only turns red then stays that way. I'm sure i am just missing some basic knowledge. Any help would be appreciated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<p id="demo">
JavaScript can change the style of an HTML element.
</p>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
x = document.getElementById("demo") // Find the element

if (x.style.color = "#000000")
    {
    x.style.color = "#ff0000";
    }
else
    {
    x.style.color = "#000000";
    }

}

</script>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used an assignment operator where you want a comparison operator. Change this:

```
if (x.style.color = "#000000");
```

to this

```
if (x.style.color == "#000000");
```

Comment: In addition, I suppose the line `x = document.getElementById("demo")` should end with a `;`

Comment: It's best practice, yeah. I've edited my own, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `if()` condition you are assinging values by `=`

It is wrong,

you should compare it by using `==`

Change you if statement as

```
if (x.style.color == "#000000")
```